# How to fix vinyl baseboard cut lines in bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, flooring, baseboard, vinyl-flooring

Is there a reason my contractor cut the floor baseboard in the bathroom like this? it looks messy, the cuts are blurry on camera but visible to person walking by. It seems to be every 4 ft.

(1) Is there any way to fix this issue? trying to find vinyl baseboard longer than 4 ft.

(2) Any precautions I should take before removing the old one and install new ones?

(3) By the way, is it called baseboard?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you consider Vinyl filler product ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is the typical "vinyl cove baseboard" it is called, used extensively in commercial buildings. It is readily available in 4' lengths and is always butted together. It can be found in rolls longer than 4 ft., but considerably more difficult to handle.

I have never had need to remove any since I have only applied it in new offices and rooms. It would seem if a stiff, wide putty knife was pushed in from the top, it would begin the removal process. Usually the adhesive in never at the top, although sometimes if too much is used it can creep up and over the edge, where it is unsightly and needs to be cleaned up. It that is evident here and there, extra care is needed in those places. For the most part, much of the glue should be concentrated in the middle, about a 3" band along the length.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try removing, they are glued so it will be a mess.

Your installer did not use the overlap cut, but the bud-head cut (straight)

Recommend you get some Vinyl filler and gently repair the seams.

Comment: I was going to remove old ones, and install new ones. are you saying it will be messy?  I dont care about the drywall, will be repainting anyways, thanks

Comment: also do you have a picture of overlap cut vs bud head, you can put in answer? I am trying to search on google

Comment: @mattsmith5 how much experience do you have with vinyl base boards. It can be tricky to install properly. Thus I first recommend you just use some vinyl filler, and if you do not like it, then you can rip them off.